# A question when using $E= - \nabla V$

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, differentiation

This problem is from Problems and Solutions on Electromagnetism.

> A thin but very massive disc of insulator has surface charge density $\sigma$ and radius $R$. A point charge $+Q$ is on the axis of symmetry. Derive an expression for the force on the charge.
>
> (Solution in the text) We can find electric potential $V(0,0,z)$ on the axis of symmetry. Then find the electric field by using the equation $E = - \nabla V$.

I don't understand how this makes sense. To get $E$ by using the equation $E = - \nabla V$, we have to know the exact form of $V(x,y,z)$. I think the logic of the above solution differentiating $V(0,0,z)$ is absurd because it is the same logic that to get a differential coefficient $f'(0)$, we can use $\frac{d}{dx}f(0)$. However, to get the answer we have to use $\left . \frac{d}{dx}f(x) \right |_{x=0} $.

How can this solution make sense?

Comment: These two questions appear to be completely unrelated. Please split this post up into two separate posts.

Comment: Okay. I'll edit it

Comment: Is it a thin disc or a thick disc?

Comment: It is thin disc contextually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you're right; if we know $V(0,0, z)$ we can only get its $z$-derivative. But the author is implicitly assuming the electric field is directed along the $z$ axis, because of the rotational symmetry of the problem. Therefore, the $z$ component of the gradient is all we care about.